# Flutter z-index in ListView - not in Stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView, for which one of the elements needs to display a drop shadow (the element is variable).

I cannot use a Stack since it's a ListView and it would be difficult to place each element. I tried to wrap in Material widget, but the shadow is only visible over the previous element in the list (there is no space (padding nor margin) between them).

Using a Container with shadow also makes the shadow show over the previous (above in the Y axis) element but behind the next (below in the Y axis) (same as with Material with elevation).

Is there a solution?

Thank you very much.

Edit: adding code

```
Container(
  width: 750,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 3,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final hasShadow = index == 1;
      return Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(hasShadow ? .7 : 0),
                blurRadius: 12,
                offset: Offset(
                  4,
                  0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ));
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: render the widget with shadow one more time each time its built!, add a postFrameCallBack in initState

Comment: Do I use this with wrapping in a widget with elevation?

Comment: And should the list re render, or the list item?

Comment: post your code where you are rendering shadow for a single widget

Comment: @Yadu I added code example, wanted to send the dartpad but I don't know how to save it